# prove $f(x)=x$ has a unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question:  Let $f$ be a continuous function from $\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $| f (x)− f (y)| ≤  \frac {1}{3} |x−y|$.

Prove $f(x)=x$ has a unique solution.

My sketch: There exists $\epsilon, \delta$ such that the following holds because $f$ is continuous
 $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \epsilon \leq \frac {1}{3} |x-y| \leq |x-y|< \delta$

Thus by the squeeze lemma, if $\delta$ goes to $0$, then $f(x)=f(y)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** begin with a point $x_0 \in \Bbb R^2$.  Consider the sequence given by
$$
x_n = f(x_{n-1})
$$
and show that its limit is uniquely determined.

Comment: How do I know that the limit of the sequence you've described above exists?

Comment: See the proof in the [link from the other answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there are two such points $x_1,x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=x_1$ and $f(x_2)=x_2$. Then $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|x_1-x_2|\leq \frac{1}{3}|x_1-x_2|$. This is true if and only if $|x_1-x_2|=0$. Therefore $x_1=x_2$ and the fixed point, if it exists, is unique.

To show that a solution does exist consider the sequence $\{x_n\}$ where $x_1=x$ for some point $x$, and $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. The limit of this sequence will end up being your fixed point!

Comment: This assumes that a solution exists

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This shows that if a solution does exist, then it is unique.

Comment: Which is fantastic, but doesn't fully answer the question

Comment: Same question as asked above.... how do I know the limit of the sequence exists?

Comment: @Zslice Do you still have this question?

Comment: I have been addressed to a Wikipedia link but I still don't understand why the limit of the sequence exists

Comment: @Zslice the best way I can explain it is, if you imagine taking $\mathbb{R}^2$, and contracting it, so pulling points inwards, then you pull them towards a point. So you can show that the limit exists by showing that the sequence is Cauchy. Or, after you contract the same point over and over again under this mapping, the distance must be getting extremely small! We can do this by using our bound of $1/3$ and giving a bound for the $n$th iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$ then

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y| \leq \frac{1}{3}|x-y|$$

which is impossible unless $x=y$. This shows that $f$ cannot have more than one fixpoint. To prove that it has one fix-points see Omnomnomnom's answer. An alternative way is to appeal directly to the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: This assumes that a solution exists

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes that is true. This only tells us that there cannot be more than one fix-point. Fixpoint itteration (like I see that you have written up) is the way to go to show that it has a solution at all.